# Filter geom_lines from ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot displaying `geom_line`s that are drawn multiple times. A toy example is shown below. I was wondering if it's possible filter out some of these lines from the `ggplot`. I have tried subsetting the data before plotting but because what im trying to plot (i.e., `ice1` in the code below) is a weird R6 object, Im not sure how to subset or sample from it.... and I can't subset from the main dataset (in this case, the Boston data).

Basically, im trying to figure out a way to not display so many of the `geom_line`s in the plot.

```
library("iml") 
library("randomForest") 
library(ggplot2)

# We train a random forest on the Boston dataset: 
data("Boston", package = "MASS") 
rf = randomForest(medv ~ ., data = Boston, ntree = 50) 
mod = Predictor$new(rf, data = Boston)

#create ICE curves
ice1 <- FeatureEffect$new(mod, method = 'pdp+ice', feature = "rm")
# get the aggregate 
aggr <- ice1$results[ice1$results$.type != "ice", ]

# create plot object
pp <-  plot(ice1, rug=FALSE) 
# plot
pp +   geom_line(aes(y = .value, group = .id, color = .value)) +  
geom_line(data = aggr, size = 2, color = "black", lineend = "round")
```

This produces something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output back to `ice1$results` after subsetting. Is this what you are looking for?

```
ice1$results <- ice1$results[ice1$results$.type != "ice", ]
```

Comment: Not exactly... So in the plot there's something like 10,000 lines being drawn. Im trying to effectively subset so there's only, say 10 or 20 lines drawn. I was trying something like this: `ice1$results <- ice1$results[seq(1, length(ice1$results$rm), 100), ]`... but this isn't working... most likely because im indexing it incorrectly.. if you check `ice1$results$rm` it is reduced to 100 observations (from 10,000) but it repeats only the 1st value

Comment: Which 10 or 20 lines you want to subset?

Comment: In my previous comment I was trying to remove the rows from 1 to 10,000 by 100. Something like this would be ideal as it would still kind of show the (vertical) range

Comment: In your previous comment you were selecting rows 1 to 10,000 by 100 and that is what `ice1$results` has but you say it is not working. So it is still not clear to me what you want.

Comment: it's not working because if you check `ice1$results$rm` after using `seq` it's just the 1st value, repeated 100 times.... not 100 different values

Comment: @Electrino Please update your post with this information of what you want. This is nowhere mentioned in your post and it is not possible for anybody to know that this is what you are expecting.